# Could not access the fax log from C#. File is being used by some other program error is coming

Tags: c#, fax

I am trying to access the IncomingLog of fax from c#. Since the windows fax and scan application is active I am not able to access the log. It throws the error it is being used by some other program.

I want to monitor the log periodically. Windows not even allow the file to be copied to another location from c#.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Within the OS a program can open a file in different modes (Share.Read, Share.Write, Share.ReadWrite, Exclusive). When even windows can't copy the file (in that case it uses Share.Read for the source file), then the file must be currently being opened in exclusive mode from the other application and you have no chance to access the file. Maybe it is still computing the file and it just needs some time, before the file is accessible for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to read the log file for incoming faxes in every 2 seconds and write to database .Can you please suggest any alternative to achieve this.

Comment: I don't know how this application works. All I can suggest is to regulary try to read the file and if it fails, just hope for the next try. I would guess that the application doesn't lock the file the whole time and that at some point able to open the file at least in Share.Read mode.

Comment: The windows fax and scan application is running always it access the log file and my program also access the log file. Whenever my program tries to access the log it throws the error currently being used my some other program

Comment: I tried to read the file using readtoend method but it is not reading the whole file. How to read the complete file using this method ? String s=file.readtoend();